# How to animate an ImageView from left to fill the screen?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I have an image set in an ImageView and I want to animate it such a way that initially nothing is displayed on the screen and the the image enters from left and go towards right and finally fill the screen

In the code that i examine the image enters from left but doesn't fill the screen and left blank behind itself

```
ObjectAnimator transAnimation= 
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView,"translationX",-100,100);
transAnimation.setDuration(3000);//set duration
transAnimation.start();//start animation
```

Comment: do you have any example? it really hard to do with your current question. Example, during the image come from left to right, it change size or not? it go to the right and how far? when it fill screen it fill width or height? which animation for fill image or no animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for animation that you posted seems to be working fine. The problem that you have is with imageview itself and the place it takes over your screen.

You said that your imageview is not taking full space and leaving blank space behind it, 
so to fix it simply make your imageview width = match_parent. and if it still doesn't work then add scaleType=centerCrop

UPDATE:

Add this code to your onCreate()

```
imageView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startImageAnimation();
        }
    });


 private void startImageAnimation() {
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "translationX",-(imageView.getWidth()), 0);
    animation.setDuration(1100);
    animation.start();
}
```

Comment: i did both of your advice . but still it goes to right and when stop , some blank space is behind it

Comment: can you add a video or a gif of your output so that we can better understand your problem please?

Comment: @FaridAbdi Updated answer. keep the width match parent and try this code for animation to make it swipe from left to right

Comment: Syntax errors are easy to fix i guess. 
Still keep startImageAnimation() method out of onCreate(). 
and if you still get errors, let me know with the error message and i'll help

Comment: @FaridAbdi Please accept this as your correct answer if it worked for you.

Comment: hi . in the above video i used that technique in a project and have some problem . when i used that technique alone before , i had no problem

Answer (score 0):

What about using **TransistionManager**?

```
            val slideRight= Slide()
            slideRight.slideEdge = Gravity.RIGHT
            slideRight.mode = Slide.MODE_IN
            slideRight.addTarget(logoImageView)
            slideRight.duration = ANIMATION_DURATION

            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(parentContainer, slideRight)
            logoImageView.visibility = VISIBLE
```

It is snippet from my working code in Kotlin

Also you can use **TransitionSet** to combine animations

Answer (score 0):

step 1: create below **left_to_right_anim** file in **anim** directory of **res**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="800" />
</set>
```

step 2:

```
//your image view
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

//name of animation from anim directory
animSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.left_to_right_anim);

// Start the animation like this
imageView.startAnimation(animSlide);
```

step 3:

now calculate time of animation and when your imageview animate at **right** side **stop** it and set it into your screen.
to achieve this you can user handler when you start your animation.
**Thread's run()** method is used to get time of your animation.
***thanks ;)***